# Rabbitmq-server instalaltion error in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to install rabbitmq. So I am facing issue as follow. For installation, I am using this [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-rabbitmq)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rabbitmq-server is already the newest version (3.8.7-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-diameter erlang-edoc erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit erlang-ic erlang-inviso erlang-nox erlang-odbc erlang-percept erlang-ssh libodbc1 libsctp1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.8.7-1) ...
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-31 17:20:23 IST; 4ms ago
  Process: 6118 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6118 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 31 17:20:23 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 installed rabbitmq-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Many times I have removed all packages of rabbitmq and installed it again but nothing worked.

I tried fixing this issue with the following command as I got from other blogs.

```
$ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get install -f
$ sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing
```

Logs after running `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service`

```
 rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-31 17:43:11 IST; 1s ago
 Process: 1878 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1878 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And logs after running `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
Aug 31 17:44:17 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: Configuring logger redirection
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.8.7
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   ##  ##
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2020 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   ######  ##
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Support:    https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Tutorials:  https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@mahesh-Latitude-3500.log
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:         /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@mahesh-Latitude-3500_upgrade.log
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Config file(s): (none)
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]:   Starting broker...
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: BOOT FAILED
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: ===========
Aug 31 17:44:19 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: Error during startup: {error,{could_not_start_listener,"::",5672,eaddrinuse}}
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: {"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{could_not_start_listener,"::",5672,eaddrinuse}}}
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: init terminating in do_boot ({error,{could_not_start_listener,::,5672,eaddrinuse}})
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: [1B blob data]
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 rabbitmq-server[3761]: Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 31 17:44:20 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 31 17:44:30 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 31 17:44:30 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 179.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit rabbitmq-server.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 31 17:44:30 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: Stopped RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 31 17:44:30 mahesh-Latitude-3500 systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ broker...
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
```

Nothing has worked. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The log prints "See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details." Have you done that? What does it say?

Comment: @schrom Added logs of both commands.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is that the port rabbitmq is trying to use is currently in use by another process.
This is stated in the output of `journalctl -xe`

```
... : Error during startup: {error,{could_not_start_listener,"::",5672,eaddrinuse}}
```

you can see all the ports currently in use on the machine with

```
$ lsof -i -P -n
```

or to check specifically for that port

```
$ lsof -i -P -n|grep 5672
```

so you could either kill the process using port `5672` or change the port used by rabbitmq